# How to code a product selection wizard on magento 1.9 using custom multi-select attributes?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, attributes

I have a magento 1.9.2 catalog containing several varieties of handmade soap. I need to code a plugin that will help the customers choose products based on custom attributes.

- Each product will have 3 multiple select attributes: `Skin conditions`, `Flagrance` and `Ingredients`. These will be visible on product page.
- Each attribute option will have:

  - Name (already available in standard CMS)
  - Short description.
  - An Url link to a dedicated CMS page with extended description (maybe external for some products). If the user clicks on the attribute he gets redirected to the description page.
  - A picture that can be changed from admin. This picture will be displayed on the product page as a thumbnails besides the option and also on the description page (update once to change everywhere).
- The description page of the attribute option will also include a list of products that have this specific option enabled.
- On the homepage there wil be a block that displays the aforemetioned 3 attributes. Clicking one of the attributes will load a list of options (with pictures) via AJAX. Click on one of the options will load vi AJAX a list of products that have the selected option enabled. Clicking on the product will redicrect to the product page.
- An admin panel for editing the the attribute options fields.

I need some advice on how to get started with this module, what architecture to use. I am novice in magento and I don't know how should I implement the custom attributes. General directions or maybe links to specific tutorials, maybe some short code snippets will suffice.